# Java - String Class, Scanner Class

Tags: java, string, class

How do I read a sentence (string) from a line of input, and print whether it represents a declarative sentence (i.e., ending in a period), interrogatory (ending in a question mark), or an exclamation (ending in exclamation point) or is not a sentence (anything else)?

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringDemo {
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        // enter a string: 
        System.out.println("Enter a string: "); 
        String dog = console.nextLine();
        dog = dog.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(dog + " has " + dog.length() +
           " letters and starts with " + dog.substring(0, 1));





        // enter another string:
        System.out.println("Enter another string: "); 
        String cat = console.nextLine();
        cat = cat.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(cat + " has " + cat.length() +
           " letters and starts with " + cat.substring(0, 1)); 

      // check contents here
      if(dog.equals(cat))
          System.out.println("Input Strings are matching ");
      else
          System.out.println("Input Strings are not matching ");
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have those brackets ( { } ) in your code?

Comment: You are missing a closing `}` to signal end of class

Comment: I took them out and still have same problem

Comment: Still error after adding closing }

Comment: did you add one to close the class? can you update the code in the question with what it is now, and the stacktrace?

Comment: just did, check it please

Comment: i have two at the end to close the class and main

Comment: The braces are now correct, but you have not declared a variable `name`

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out. it was "name" had to be changed to "cat" or "dog" lol

Comment: neither do you need it. change the references to 'name' with references to 'dog'

Comment: @m.daooo not to "cat", nor to "dog". simply to cat or dog (no quotation marks around it)

Comment: @m.daooo mark the question as solved, otherwise people will keep posting answers

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, could you please help me again?

Comment: by calling it. string1.equals(string2);

Comment: so i have dog.equals(cat);
where is the output?

Comment: it is returned by that statement: boolean b = dog.equals(cat);

Comment: so it just evaluates to either true or false? doesnt output anything, right?

Comment: why would it output anything? there 's no logic in that. you can provide output based on the result, but no, there's no visual output (which couldn't be there, since the equals method can not possibly know whether you are working on the command line, in a Swing gui, in a JavaFX gui, with JSP/JSF, ... )

Comment: How can I read a sentence (string) from a line of input, and print whether it represents a declarative sentence (i.e., ending in a period), interrogatory (ending in a question mark), or an exclamation (ending in exclamation point) or is not a sentence (anything else)?

Comment: @m.daooo please don't ask questions like this: for every new question, start a new thread. otherwise it'll be impossible to verify what we're answering to.

Comment: The original question (and the one after that) are already answered. New questions should be asked in a new thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to use .equals() method to check content equality as below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StringDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

            // enter a string: 
            System.out.println("Enter a string: "); 
            String dog = console.nextLine();
            dog = dog.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(dog + " has " + dog.length() +
               " letters and starts with " + dog.substring(0, 1));





            // enter another string:
            System.out.println("Enter another string: "); 
            String cat = console.nextLine();
            cat = cat.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(cat + " has " + cat.length() +
               " letters and starts with " + cat.substring(0, 1)); 

           // check contents here
          if(dog.endsWith("?"))
              System.out.println("Input Strings ends in a question mark ");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I updated the question, thanks again but could you help again?

Comment: You can make use of endsWith() of string as boolean retVal = Str.endsWith( "." );. If it returns true check is correct